# IOS - UITableView.registerClass() - Why do you pass class AND identifier?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I give in. I must be missing something simple and primary here!

**Question**

- Why do you pass an identifier to  `UITableView.registerClass()`?
- What is `identifier` used for?
- What breaks when you toss in garbage for the `identifier`?

**Source of Question**

Ref: `func registerClass(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`

Example:  `tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell");`

**Reference**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass in an identifier to later get a `UITableViewCell` via that same identifier. If you pass in garbage you have to pass in the same garbage to access it.

Normally in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you write something like

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The identifier you use there has to correspond with the identifier you previously registered.

*Why do you pass an identifier to `UITableView.registerClass()`?*

To be able to get the a cell with that identifier later on

*What is identifier used for?*

Same as above

*What breaks when you toss in garbage for the identifier?*

Nothing, you either have to access the cell via the same garbage later on or you cannot get it out if you pass in something random or stuff like that.

Comment: hmm. I'll do some research on this tonight, and be in touch! :)

Comment: This answer leaves out the important part. A table can have multiple types of cells in it. So you may need to call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` with different identifiers to get the proper type of cell for the given row.

Comment: this now makes a lot of sense, thank you luk2302 and rmaddy!!! I do not understand 'what' identifiers are used for, even after a decent amount of research but now I see that they allow delineation and identification of cells, cool! Thank you guys!